# Display Custom Taxonomy Terms in Responsive Columns using Semantic Grid

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, grid, multiple-columns

I am using a WP theme that includes the semantic grid.

For example, if I want to create 3 responsive columns I can use the following markup in a post or page:

```
<div class="grid-33">
Column 1
</div>
<div class="grid-33">
Column 2
</div>
<div class="grid-33">
Column 3
</div>
```

I am using php to grab and display a list of term links from a custom taxonomy I am using with Woocommerce. It works nicely to create a list. The problem is that the list is very long.

The echo section of the php is as follows:

```
echo "<h1 class='vendor-title'>MY TITLE</h1>"; 
        echo "<p class='vendor-subtext'>My subtext.</p>";
        echo "<ul class='vendor-list'>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) .'">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo "</ul>";
```

What I want to do is to format the PHP so that the resulting list is displayed in 3 responsive columns using semantic grid-33 class divs.

How can I code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution for this. You can use `column-count` and `column-gap` css instead to style the list.

You can change the column count using `@media` break points to have less columns on tablet and phone view.

For example:

```
.vendor-list {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -ms-column-count:4;
    -ms-column-gap:10px;
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .vendor-list {    
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 5px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
    -ms-column-count:2;
    -ms-column-gap:5px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 5px;
}
}
```

Comment: I remember you that your initial question is related to [**semantic grids**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_grid) and your answer here doesn't really answers that. So please avoid it, as if you do it this way, nobody will want to answer your questions, because you are not playing the game and it's not fair.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where is the difficulty… Now you may have to get to correct class for the container:

```
echo '<h1 class="vendor-title">MY TITLE</h1>
<p class="vendor-subtext">My subtext.</p>
<div class="vendor-list grid-container">';

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<div class="grid-33"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) .'">' . $term->name . '</a></div>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Loic.  I ticked this solution as well because it does echo the columns correctly. But the CSS based solution is better because it is much easier to style columns based on screen size.  Thanks very much for your input.

Comment: I upticked.  Thanks for your help.  But the answer I provided below is much easier to style.

Comment: @khunmax  I upticked yours. Thanks. Your answer is only good when one text content fills separated columns, but **has nothing to do with [Semantic Grid columns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_grid) as defined in the web. You can also have a look to [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com/examples/grid.html) system.